# redbeans use existing database connection

Tags: redbean

Is there any easy way to use a existing database connection with Redbeans. E.g. if I first connect using another PDO database class, and then I want Redbeans to use this open connection? I am primarily using MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it actually is quite easy:

Just connect like this to a PDO database, e.g.

```
$dbh = new PDO(
            $url,
            $username,
            $password, 
            $options
);
```

And then:

```
R::setup($dbh);
```

Then you use the same connection.